# Audio is lost in some portions of a HLS stream

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have setup a HLS live stream on AWS. Significant part of the video plays as expected but in some portions audio is lost while the video continues to play. Please share you thoughts/insights if you have faced such an issue.

I transcode video to h264, baseline3.1 and audio to aac stereo 2 channels before segmenting to 10s files. Following commands are being used:

1. Transcoding:
   `ffmpeg -y -i ${file_path} -b:v ${vBitrate} -minrate ${vBitrate} -maxrate ${vBitrate} -c:v libx264 -b:a ${aBitrate} -c:a libfaac -ac 2 -r 25 -s ${resolution} -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 ${output_dir}/${file_name}.ts`
   Ex: vBitrate: 1m, aBirate: 128k, resolution: 960x540
2. Splittting:
   `ffmpeg -i ${file_path} -c:v copy -c:a copy -flags -global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time ${segment} -segment_list ${output_dir}/playlist.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts tmp0/${file_name}_%02d.ts`
   Ex: segment: 10

*Setup:* segments are being served from Nginx and playlist is managed by a Python/Flask app.

Comment: Would be good if you can add the command line. Does the audio come back after it was gone? Does it still match the video timestamps (is it still on time)?

Comment: @Boehmi Yes, after a while audio resumes and video/audio are in sync. Also, if I refresh, audio resumes.

Comment: @Boehmi added command line